# Image Overlap and animation

Tags: html, css

Am trying to animate an image (that uses class="under") and is overlapped by a still image (that uses class="over"). Animation effect works fine for the lower image with Firefox and IE-9 browsers, whereas Chrome does not show animation. Chrome shows both still images.
Any solution please.

---

```
.under
{
border-style: solid;
border-color: #0000ff;
border-radius:15px;
position: absolute;
left:173px;
top:0px;
z-index: 1;
}
.over
{
position:relative;
left:100px;
top:20px;
z-index: 2;
border-radius: 15px;
}


@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
```

}

```
#animate-area   { 

        width: 1000px; 
        height: 160px; 

        background-image: url(images/img7.jpg);
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        opacity: 0.4;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */

    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;

}
```

---

Thanks
Anand

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground

```
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
to { background-position: 100% 0; }
```

}

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
to { background-position: 100% 0; }
```

}

Comment: Hi Valeriu, thanks, yes it works fine now with the changes you have suggested.